# is it possible to call a Microservice (spring boot) from a Camunda service Task?

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

Workflow -> (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgtiD.png)
Is it possible to call a microservice from a Camunda task?

1.The start event will received a Json with a client data .
2.The service task should connect to a microservice (spring boot) that stores the data in the database.-> just need to pass the json with the info to the micro and then should complete the task.
3. if the previous task is completed this task should run.

is there a way to do it? I am very new at camunda.

External Task but it didnt work

Comment: Absolutely. It is what Camunda does. It would be good if you shared the Camunda version (7 or 8?) and an example of what you tried (see guidelines).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, check for documentation :

```
@Component
@ExternalTaskSubscription("scoreProvider") // create a subscription for this topic name
public class ProvideScoreHandler implements ExternalTaskHandler {

  @Override
  public void execute(ExternalTask externalTask, ExternalTaskService externalTaskService) {

    // only for the sake of this demonstration, we generate random data
    // in a real-world scenario, we would load the data from a database
    String customerId = "C-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(32);
    int creditScore = (int) (Math.random() * 11);

    VariableMap variables = Variables.createVariables();
    variables.put("customerId", customerId);
    variables.put("creditScore", creditScore);

    // complete the external task
    externalTaskService.complete(externalTask, variables);

    Logger.getLogger("scoreProvider")
        .log(Level.INFO, "Credit score {0} for customer {1} provided!", new Object[]{creditScore, customerId});
  }

}
```

[Spring boot with Camunda example](https://camunda.com/blog/2021/03/external-task-client-spring-bootified/)